# getting html source code with dynamic content to do regular expression analysis

Tags: php, jquery, curl

In My project I need to get the html content of another webpage in our server. The problem is that particular page has some dynamic content and I need the data in that content to do a regx analysis.

sample content from the page

```
    <div id="loading" class="loading">ESPERE UN MOMENTO POR FAVOR...<br /><img src="images/cargador.gif" border="0" alt="ESPERE UN MOMENTO POR FAVOR..." /></div>
<p></p>
<div class="tabla_d">
<form method="post" action="xxx">
<div id="nresults"></div>
</form>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
function checkavailability() {
    jQuery("#loading").slideDown();
    jQuery.post("cart.php", { a: "noptions", sld: jQuery("#sld").val(), tld: jQuery("#tld").val(), checktype: 'transfer', ajax: 1 },
    function(data){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '550px'}, 800);
        jQuery("#nresults").html(data);
        jQuery("#nresults").slideDown();
        jQuery("#loading").slideUp();
    });
}
```

The content is loaded in the div tag with `id="nreults"`. I can view the data when I inspect the element but I am not able to get the data using CURL. Is there any way I can do this? I am pretty new and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That div has data loaded in asynchronously, meaning that the browser loads in the content with javascript. CURL just returns you the standard output from the page before any processing is done. AFAIK it's not possible to capture this information.

Comment: @phpisuber01: Well not by hitting the page with the JS, but he could cURL a `POST` request to `cart.php` just like the JS does and get that... which is what he seems to be after in the first place. Of course he would need to figure out what all the post values needed to be.

Comment: Is it possible to Curl a Post data and if so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. You would need to use cURL to send the same request the javascript makes which would return you not the entire page, but the HTML thats dynamically loaded into `#nresults`.

```
$ch = curl_init('cart.php');

$values = array(
   'sld' => 'you need to figure out what this value should be',
   'a' => 'noptions',
   'tld' => 'you need to figure what this value should be',
   'checktype' => 'transfer',
   'ajax' => 1
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $values);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

// run your regex on $html, though you probably dont want to do that
// you should probably use DOMDocument instead to operate on the DOM
// Unless you are just looking for a partuclar sring of text that has nothing
// to do with the HTML structure of the document.
```